# How to put a value to the objects using setter Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, set, this, getter

I have some issue about using a setter in JavaScript. 
An issue with set method, when I want to set value of property `lastName` or `firstName` nothing happens.
Would you be so kind to give me any advice, about how can I solve it? 
Thank you in advance

```
function User(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
        'firstName': {
            get: function(){
                var _that = this;
                var str = _that.fullName.split(' ');
                return str[0];
            },
            set: function(name){
                var split = this.fullName.split(' ');
                name = split[0];
            }
        },
        'lastName': {
            get: function(){
                var _that = this;
                var str = _that.fullName.split(' ');
                return str[1];
            },
            set: function(name){
                var split = this.fullName.split(' ');
                name = split[1];
            }
        }
    })
};
var fred = new User("Freedy House");
console.log(fred.fullName); //Freedy House
fred.firstName = 'Nossssssu'
console.log(fred.firstName); //It stil the old value
```

Comment: `name = split[0];` doesn't set an object property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually setting anything in your set methods. Try this:

```
set: function(lastName){
    var firstName = this.fullName.split(' ')[0];
    this.fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

Though, this whole thing is kinda pointless, you can just keep first name and last name as separate fileds.